# create lists from google sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets

[image: Google Sheet sample]

I have a google sheet looks like the image, how could I create two lists using Python.
list_1 = [Country,State,State,State,City,City,City,City]
list_2 = [USA,California,Washington ,New York,San Francisco, Los Angeles,Seattle,New York City]
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
#read a excel sheet
sheed_df = pd.read_excel("<path to excel sheet>")
list_1 = []
list_2 = []
title = []
number = []
# find index of each header and find name of the header 
# header means the value filling list_1
for num in range (sheed_df['No'].valus):
    title_row = sheed_df[sheed_df['No'] == num]
    topic = title_row ['Topic'].values[0]
    title.append(topic)
    number.append(title_row.index.values[0])
number.append(sheed_df.tail(1).index.valus[0])
# now you have all information and you can create a list
for i , j in enumerate(title):
     counters = 1
     if i+1 <= len(number):
         for itr in range (number[i+1]-number[i]):
              index_topic = number[i] + counters 
              list_1.append(j)
              list_2.append(sheed_df.iloc[index_topic,1])
              counters = counters + 1
```

Comment: While it i good to provide an answer, perhaps comment the code to explain it to others?

Comment: Hi Marya, Thank you so much for your reply! I am new to pandas.
I got error like 'only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index'
May I know topic = title_row ['Topic'].values[0], here, is values[0] same as values[0:]? Thanks!