# generating lists from google sheet

Tags: python, google-sheets

[image]

I have a google sheet looks like the image, how could I create two lists using Python. list_1 = [Country,State,State,State,City,City,City,City] list_2 = [USA,California,Washington ,New York,San Francisco, Los Angeles,Seattle,New York City] Thanks!

Comment: Also you already asked this exact question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71055509/create-lists-from-google-sheet Don't ask duplicate questions. If you have a problem with the answer in that question, ask the person who wrote the answer or ask another question about the specific problem you encountered

Comment: Also also: looking through your previous questions, you seem to have misunderstood the purpose of Stack Overflow. This is not the place to ask "how could I do this?" You need to [do your own research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/843953) first and ask once you have a _specific_ question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [create lists from google sheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71055509/create-lists-from-google-sheet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will generate lists based on row values. `NaN` should be excluded while doing the task.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_excel('sample.xlsx')

total_no = df.loc[~df['No'].isnull(),'No'].tolist()  #adding total No. values (excluding NaN)
total_topic = []
list_1= []
list_2 = []
for num,topic in zip(df['No'].tolist(), df['Topic'].tolist()):
    if num in total_no:
        total_topic.append(topic)
    elif type(topic) == float:  #excluding NaN for topics
        continue
    else:
        list_1.append(total_topic[-1])
        list_2.append(topic)

print(list_1)  
print(list_2)
```